Lower bound for online binary decision making with expert advice
Suppose we want to make a sequence on $n$ binary decisions with advice from $k$ experts. We define the regret with respect to the best expert we get advice from. Now I want to prove that we are going to enjoy at least $\Omega(m)$ regret where $m=\min \{n,\log k\}$. When $n>\log k$ the situation is clear for me, but for the other case I don't know how to proceed.
